# Javascript :restructuring JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response from the server like -

```
[
  {
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9E6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "CATEGORY": "Power Cutter",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "POWER CUTTER",
    "ParentCategoryName": "Small Household Appliances",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
  },
  {
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9F6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "CATEGORY": "Rotary Tool Kit",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ROTARY TOOL KIT",
    "ParentCategoryName": "Small Household Appliances",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
  },
  {
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303DFF6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A566F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "CATEGORY": "Enlarger",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ENLARGER",
    "ParentCategoryName": "Cameras & Photography",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
  },
  {
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303E006F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A566F70E053421F080A5AF3",
    "CATEGORY": "Flash Transceiver",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
    "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "FLASH TRANSCEIVER",
    "ParentCategoryName": "Cameras & Photography",
    "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
  },
]
```

I want to restructure the data as below -

```
[
    {
        "ParentCategoryName": "Cameras & Photography",
        "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
        "Category":
        [
            {
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "FLASH TRANSCEIVER",
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303E006F70E053421F080A5AF3"                  
            },
            {
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ENLARGER",
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303DFF6F70E053421F080A5AF3"                  
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ParentCategoryName": "Small Household Appliances",
        "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
        "Category": 
        [
            {
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ROTARY TOOL KIT",
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9F6F70E053421F080A5AF3"                  
            },
            {
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "POWER CUTTER",
                "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9E6F70E053421F080A5AF3"                  
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Could anyone please help me with Javascript code to restructure the JSON.
I am unable to get the structuring right.

Thanks

Comment: try using underscore.js

Comment: `I want to restructure the data as below` - you'll never get that structure as it is not valid javascript object - perhaps you require it in [this](http://pastebin.com/hQ0Jnqys) format

Comment: I suggest you go back and take another look at what a JavaScript object is, and what an array is. `[ParentCategoryName: ...]` is neither, and is invalid, and does not mean anything. Once you've decided what it is you actually want, study up on how to iterate through an array, and/or access properties of an object, and/or how to create new objects, such as using object literal notation. If you run into trouble, then please come back and ask a question.

Comment: @Omhs There's absolutely no problem in restructuring object data  and I would gladly be of assistance. Probably write a code that would enable you to do so. But the problem is: Your data are not corresponding. For instance there is no "CD Shelf System" in the source (where do we get that from or how? ) etc - so  you need to fix them before we'd be able to help.

Comment: @BekimBacaj - i have edited the Required JSON. I have corrected the data as well. Could you please help me with it

Comment: @torazaburo - Thanks for highlighting it. I have edited the question now with the correct required JSON. I am working on the code to restructure it, will get back with further queries

Comment: @Omhs, sorry for delay, hope your life didn't depend on it :) - bellow is the working code.

Comment: @BekimBacaj - You are a savior. I came up with a solution but the code was not optimized. Your code is much neat and effective. Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you'd like to store the restructured list of assets or save a copy, use  ***JSON.stringify*** to get a clean content and write to file or wherever you'd like.

How to use:

```
var restructured = listReCompile( [sourceObject] );
```

The live object returned, will also contain properties & provide direct access link to *"ParentClientId"* code which will get you straight to the list of available assets in that category for convenience.

Regards.

```js
function listReCompile(x) {

  var i = 0, m = [];
  while ( x[i] ) { var o = {}, so = {};

    if ( x[i]["ParentClientId"] in m ) {

      so["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME"] = x[i]["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME"];
      so["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID"] = x[i]["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID"];
      m[ x[i]["ParentClientId"] ].push( so );

    }
    else
    {
      o["ParentCategoryName"] = x[i]["ParentCategoryName"];
      o["ParentClientId"] = x[i]["ParentClientId"];
      o["Category"] = [];

      so["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME"] = x[i]["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME"];
      so["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID"] = x[i]["ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID"];

      o.Category.push( so );

      m[ x[i]["ParentClientId"] ] = o.Category;
      m.push( o );
    }
    i++;
  }
  return m;
};

var source = [{
  "ParentCategoryName": "Cameras & Photography",
  "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A566F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "CATEGORY": "Flash Transceiver",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "FLASH TRANSCEIVER",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303E006F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",

  "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
}, {
  "ParentCategoryName": "Cameras & Photography",
  "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A566F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "CATEGORY": "Enlarger",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ENLARGER",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303DFF6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
}, {
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9E6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "CATEGORY": "Power Cutter",
  "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "POWER CUTTER",
  "ParentCategoryName": "Small Household Appliances",
  "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
}, {
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_ID": "3EB06E303C9F6F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "ParentClientId": "3EB06E303A596F70E053421F080A5AF3",
  "CATEGORY": "Rotary Tool Kit",
  "ASSET_CATALOG_GROUP_TYPE": "PRODUCT",
  "ASSET_CLIENT_CATALOG_NAME": "ROTARY TOOL KIT",
  "ParentCategoryName": "Small Household Appliances",
  "ASSET_CATALOG_LEVEL": 2
} ];

var restructured = listReCompile( source );

console.log( restructured );
```